# How do I see what things X is doing?

Tags: linux

There's quite a few things that I've only figured out how to do through the gui, but I'd like to use those functions in scripts (changing from speakers to headphones, connecting to PEAP wireless networks, etc.).

Is there a way (perhaps a log or a trace) to see what the X server is doing (I'm assuming it is making bash commands of some sort)?

Comment: My guess/hope is that most of this is actually accomplished using DBus communication at some level, not "well-known" shell scripts, so you could try looking at what DBus does using [dbus-monitor](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html), and then emit those same messages from your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

1) The X server is only displaying stuff. You can trace what it is doing, but that won't help answer your real questions.

2) Various utility programs use the X server to display a GUI, and they do the actual work. You can trace those programs, too, but that would be too low level to help you.

3) Changing from speakers to headphones: Look at Pulseaudio, scriptable with `pacmd`.

4) Connecting to wireless networks: Look at network manager, especially 'nmcli', or bypass it and use `wpa-supplicant` directly (via `wpa_cli` or configuration).

DBus will also work in many cases, but it's more of a pain to script.